# What does "finality" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

I use this link but i don't quite understand it: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/finality?q=finality+

"Not only does this call into question the finality of individual payments, it also means that a cryptocurrency can simply stop functioning, resulting in a complete loss of value."

Source: http://www.ibtimes.com/bigger-cryptocurrencies-get-worse-they-perform-bis-2691889

Comment: **Finality** is a technical term in monetary and settlement systems and refers to the point of irrevocability as it relates to a payment transaction.  You should look this up not in a standard dictionary  but in a textbook on currencies and international exchange.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo -- Your comment would make a good answer, especially if you provided a link to a brief explanation of the concept from such a textbook.

Answer (score 2):

***Finality*** is a noun form of the adjective ***final***, referring to the characteristic of being final. The equivalent in the more common pattern is to use the suffix *-ness*, like *stillness* or *bigness*, but the *-ity* suffix also occurs a fair amount, such as *futility* for *futile*.

If a decision, or a financial transaction, or a result in a sports match, is *final*, then it is irrevocable and settled with no ability to back out or change it. Thus *finality* is the quality that "individual payments" have when they are *final*:  they cannot be *undone*.